# Sublime Syntax Match First Line of the File

Tags: regex, syntax, sublimetext3

I'm trying to match just the first line of a file with sublime 3 syntax highlighting assuming it does not feature a leading number.

```
    <dict>
        <key>comment</key>
        <string>Matchs the first line comment</string>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>\A^[^0-9].*</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>comment</string>
    </dict>
```

The expression works with ctrl-f but will highlight the entire document when used in the syntax file.

Comment: can you be more specific in what you mean with "matching" the first line?

Comment: Just the first line of the file. For this old language, the first line of the file is a comment unless it starts with a numeric.

Comment: It's possible Sublime's syntax highlighter treats `\A` the same as `^`. (It's one or the other, BTW; `\A^` is redundant.)  But try this: `\A(?!\d).*$`

Comment: if you create a [sublime-syntax](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) file instead of a legacy tmLanguage, you can create a match regex without needing to use `\A`, and then set to a different context after the first line.

Comment: Thanks @keith-hall, I converted the tmLanguage file using the tools>developer>New Syntax from *.tmLangugue. Than added 'main:
    - match: "^[^0-9].*"
      comment: Matchs the first line comment
      scope: comment
    - match: "\n"
      push: body

  body:'

Answer (score 0):

first of all, use the yaml variant so you can see what you're doing lol.

answer: have main be your first line mode. as soon as you see the end of any line, switch to another mode for everything else. never set back to main - other lines mode is your god now. pushing and popping should work as expected since we use set instead of push (so main is not even on the stack any more).

```
 main: # aka first line mode
  - match: '$'
    set: other.lines
  - match: '.*'
    scope: first.line

 other.lines:
  - match: '.*'
    scope: every.other.line
```

as for the number bit, you can just add that into your $ match as an alternative first line deal breaker regex

```
  - match: '^\d|$'
    set: other.lines
```

for bonus points, if you only want to match certain formats of the first line, just have all of them set after you scope, and then add the $ rule as well. if you want to ignore whitespace up until that point, you'll need to set as soon as you peek ahead and see an invalid first line, and when you do set to the normal body matcher. like say you wanted to highlight a first line only if that first line says foo, foobar, or foobaz. maybe something like...

```
 main:
  - match: 'foo(bar|baz)?'
    scope: valid.first.line
    set: other.lines # done with the first line
  - match: '(?=^\s*\S)'
    set: other.lines # looked ahead, saw non blank line, wasnt valid first line
```